# @Component always null in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, code-injection

I have two classes which are annotated as @Component

```
@Component
public class ClientMapper {
  public Client convert(ClientEntity clientEntity) {
    Client client = new Client();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(clientEntity, client);
    return client;
  }

  public ClientEntity convert(Client client) {
    ClientEntity clientEntity = new ClientEntity();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(client, clientEntity);
    return clientEntity;
  }
}
```

```
@Component
public class OrderMapper {
  public Order convert(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
    Order order = new Order();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(orderEntity, order);
    return order;
  }

  public OrderEntity convert(Order order) {
    OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(order, orderEntity);
    return orderEntity;
  }
}
```

I injected them into different services

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

  private final ClientMapper clientMapper;
  private final ClientRepository clientRepository;
```

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

  private final OrderMapper orderMapper;
  private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
  private final OrderNumberRepository orderNumberRepository;
```

But all time my mappers is null. I don't create new Object of them using new command. Also with my repository interfaces everything is fine, so my way to inject my comments(@AllArgsContrustor) works correct.
[image: screen of code where you can see that mapper is null]
Little note, I have tests classes where I used @InjectMocks on my services classes. Can it be that my error occupied because of this annotation?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class OrderServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private OrderRepository orderRepository;
  @InjectMocks
  private OrderServiceImpl orderService;
```

Comment: how are you injecting the beans?

Comment: I tried several variants. Now as you can see I used AllArgsConstructor annotation. But also I tried RequiredArgsConstructor, default constructor without annotations and Autowired annotation under my mapper and repository. No one of this variants didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `MockitoExtension`, spring won't create component of OrderMapper.
If you need actual implementation. Use `@Spy` annotation of MockitoExtension.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class OrderServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private OrderRepository orderRepository;
  @Spy
  private OrderMapper orderMapper = new OrderMapper(); // Note: new OrderMapper() is optional as you have No Argument Constructor
  @InjectMocks
  private OrderServiceImpl orderService;
```

Or as a practice `@Mock` is always best way to go instead of `@Spy` incase of Unit test.